# Converted date strings to timestamp, now can't perform timestamp math in Hive

Tags: datetime, hive

I have a hive table as follows:

```
incident_id      string
incident_time    timestamp
call_id          string 
call_time        timestamp
```

I originally converted the timestamp values from strings using

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(incident_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')) as timestamp) as incident_time
```

I did a quick select * and they all look good.  I'm trying to find which records have a incident_time between 1 hour before call_time and up to 48 hours after.  My query is:

```
select * from mydb.mytable where 
(incident_time >= call_time-3600) and  
(incident_time <= call_time+172800);
```

This throws an error Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive 2 Internal error: unsupported conversion from type: interval_day_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by using the datediff function in hive.

```
select distinct * 
from 
mydb.mytable  
where 
datediff(incident_time, call_time) <= 1;
```

found the answer at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12729